# Android: ZoomIn but keep scale of element

Tags: java, android, kotlin, zooming, scale

I'm trying to zoom in on an PDF element inside my view but keep the scale of it. When i try to do a zoom animation it changes the scale of the element and i can't zoom out because of that. When the scale is 1 i can easily zoom in and zoom out from it.

I have tried animations (with `Animations` and `Animator`)

I have also tried multiple examples but without success..

The point is: can I zoom in on an element like a pinch zoom but with code without messing up the scale?

Thank You in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library, first of all you should add this line to gradle,

```
implementation 'com.ablanco.zoomy:zoomy:1.1.0'
```

Then you should use this code;

```
 val builder = Zoomy.Builder(context).
        target(feedDetailImage/* The image you want to zoom */)
        .animateZooming(true)
        .enableImmersiveMode(false)
        .tapListener {
        }
    builder.register()
```

Comment: This library just allows me to zoom in/out the element, which I already can. Does it have a zoom to a certain point function that i can call when i build it? I've read the library but I didn't find anything useful.. @Murat Çakır